# Regex pattern doesn't work for 2 characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to create a regex pattern to validate names which would support alphabets, acute accent characters and including these 2 special characters **-** **.**

This is the pattern and it works as expected but only after I enter a 3rd character!

So, it doesn't work for 2 characters and returns **false**.

```
/^[a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\.\-]([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-]+)([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-]$)/.test('RE')
```

It works perfectly for >=3 characters and returns **true**.

```
/^[a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\.\-]([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-]+)([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-]$)/.test('REG')
```

What could be going wrong with the pattern which doesn't work for chars less than 3?

Does somebody here recognize this?

Comment: The `+` modifier means "one or more", together with the pattern at the start and the end of your regex, you effectively require that there are at least 3 letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern explicitly requires three or more characters:

1. One to match `[a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\.\-]`
2. One or more to match `([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-]+)`
3. One to match `([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-])`

You haven't said what you want the pattern to do and why you're capturing the middle and final bit separately, but ***if*** you want to capture the "middle" and the end separately, change the `+` quantifier to `*` instead; a two-character string will capture the empty string for the first capturing group:

```
/^[a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\.\-]([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-]*)([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-])$/
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

```js
const rex = /^[a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\.\-]([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-]*)([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-])$/;

function test(str) {
    const match = rex.exec(str);
    console.log(`String:  ${str}`)
    console.log(`Result:  ${match ? "match" : "no match"}`);
    if (match ) {
      console.log(`Group 1: ${match[1]}`);
      console.log(`Group 2: ${match[2]}`);
    }
}

test("RE");
test("REG");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or perhaps you meant to capture everything after the first char (since the second and third classes are the same):

```
/^[a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\.\-]([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-]+)$/
```

```js
const rex = /^[a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\.\-]([a-zA-ZßẞüÜöÖäÄÑñÁáÀàÂâÉéÈèÊêËëÍíÌìÎîÏïĲĳÓóÒòÔôÚúÙùÛûÝýŸÿ\s\.\-]+)$/;

function test(str) {
    const match = rex.exec(str);
    console.log(`String:  ${str}`)
    console.log(`Result:  ${match ? "match" : "no match"}`);
    if (match ) {
      console.log(`Group 1: ${match[1]}`);
    }
}

test("RE");
test("REG");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: The description was a bit off because the regex in the question was changed in a ninja edit, but I've fixed it now. If it seems off, hit refresh.

Comment: Couldn't figure that out myself. That worked perfectly fine and a good explanation about how that works. Thanks for the help. I will accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

But your pattern is matching 3 chars min? If you rewrite it:

```
/^[<char>(<char>+)<char>$/
```

It is three chars min